# How do I retrain an already trained TensorFlow model with new data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2

I have already trained a deep learning model with some data and it performs well with the test data. Now, how do I retrain this model when I get new data?

Comment: You can save it. You can use pickle.

Comment: I already have the model saved as h5 file. I want to retrain this model with new data.

Comment: It depends on your model.  Some models allow transfer learning.

Answer (score 2):

You can Save your model using

```
keras.model.save(yourModel, 'fileName.hdf5')
```

After you got the data you can load your saved model

```
model = keras.model.load_model('fileName.hdf5')
model.fit()
```

The training will continue from last saved weights, optimizer and loss.